# How to add LDAP user to existing local group in RHEL?

Tags: linux, user-accounts, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm attempting to add some of our LDAP users to a locally defined group on our RHEL server, however I get an error stating that the LDAP user is not found in /etc/passwd.

What would be the best way to allow LDAP users to be added to local groups?

My feeling is that this must be done manually. I could edit: `/etc/group` and add the LDAP group to the list. Would that be ideal?

```
[server]# id apache
uid=409(apache) gid=409(apache) groups=409(apache) context=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0
[server]# id john.doe
uid=11389(john.doe) gid=6097(ABC_Corporate_US) groups=6097(ABC_Corporate_US) context=user_u:system_r:unconfined_t:s0
[server]# /usr/sbin/usermod -a -G apache john.doe
usermod: john.doe not found in /etc/passwd
```

OS: RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga))
Note: Updating the OS on this machine is not an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `gpasswd`:

```
gpasswd -a john.doe apache
```